# App Engine 1.8.9 instances and high latency

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I have a PHP application running on AppEngine and it was working fine until today. A few hours ago I realized that it was experiencing some problems. From the log console I observed that all the requests had a latency close to 60 secs and the following errors were returned with each response:

> PHP Fatal error: The request was aborted because it exceeded the maximum execution time. in /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/runtime/RealApiProxy.php on line 50
>       E 13:36:58
>   PHP Fatal error: The request was aborted because it exceeded the maximum execution time. in /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/ext/session/MemcacheSessionHandler.php on line 139
>       E 13:36:58
>   PHP Fatal error: The request was aborted because it exceeded the maximum execution time. in /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/ext/session/MemcacheSessionHandler.php on line 120

After a while I realized that most of the active instances were running the AppEngine 1.8.9 version. Only one of them was running the 1.8.8 (version used in the development), and although the latency was still high, this one was working fine. I've been looking for this 1.8.9 version but I could not find any documentation.

I am kind of lost and I don't know where to start to fix this problem. I don't even know if the problem comes from Google or from my application. Is it possible to force the instances to be created using a given app engine version?

Any clue or advice would be really helpful.

Comment: Can you email your app id to amyu@google.com ?

Comment: this happens quite regularly that Google releases new version of runtime few days before any official announcements. I guess they are just making all of the users lab rats to tune up the release.

Comment: Yeh we need to app id - perhaps you want to file this in the issue tracker? https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/FilingIssues?tm=3

Comment: Thanks @AmyU., I have already sent you the app id

Comment: I have also filed this in the issue tracker as @StuartLangley suggested. Thanks for the answers.